# Regex Capture one word OR two words in quotes

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to implement gmail style filters in my search and I'm stuck at this regex problem. I need to capture ONE word OR two words in quotes (but without the quotation marks themselves) This is PCRE (PHP)

ie.

```
name:mark
```

desired result: 1st capture group should be mark

```
name:"mark"
```

desired result: 1st capture group should be mark

```
name:"mark wilson"
```

desired result: 1st capture group should be mark, second capture group should be wilson

```
name:mark wilson
```

desired result: 1st capture group should be mark, wilson is ignored

The closest I've gotten is name:(\w+|\"\w+(?>\"|\s([a-z.'-]+\"))) it captures example 1 perfectly, but example 2 still includes the quotes, and example 3 ends up as:

group 1: "mark wilson"  (quotes included)

group 2: wilson"        (quote included)

I've tried lookahead and lookbehinds but I'm not getting anywhere with those either

any help would be very appreciated. tia

Comment: You might want to use multiple matching, like in `(?:\G(?!\A)\h*"?|:"?)\K\w+`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qm59Ae/1).

Comment: the matches need to be in groups in order to extracted for search purposes. it's not just a matter of a boolean matching operation unfortunately otherwise this would work.

Comment: The main point is that you cannot do that for arbitrary amount of groups, you must specify them all in the pattern. Like in https://regex101.com/r/qm59Ae/2. You might use `\w+:(?|(\w+)|"(\w+)(?:\h+(\w+))?(?:\h+(\w+))?")` and add more `(?:\h+(\w+))?` patterns at the end to support up to N amount of optional words

Comment: bro I think you just got it. `\w+:(?|(\w+)|"(\w+)(?:\h+(\w+))?(?:\h+(\w+))?")` seems to work perfectly

@WiktorStribiżew can you post this as an answer & I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 option could be using an [if/else clause](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html#check_relgroup) which will give mark in group 2 and wilson in group 3. The first group will capture the `"` which can be used for the if else checking for the existence for group 1.

```
\w+:(")?(\w+(?:\h+(\w+))?)(?(1)")
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uRL32m/1)

If the space after the first name should not be there, you could also group that and have the values in group 3 and 4

```
\w+:(")?((\w+)(?:\h+(\w+))?)(?(1)")
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RieKEc/1)

You could also get either the single value between quotes or not, or capture the first or second name in a capturing group using a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html)

---

```
\w+:(?|"(\w+)(?:\h+(\w+))?"|(\w+))
```

**Explanation**

- `\w+:` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?|` Branch reset group

  - `"(\w+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ word chars
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\h+` match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
    - `(\w+)` Capture group 2, match 1+ word chars
  - `)?` Close group and make optional
  - `"` Match `"`
  - `|` Or
  - `(\w+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ word chars
- `)` Close branch reset group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P5NFVw/1)

Comment: This is very close, but on the 4th example name:mark wilson it is still capturing wilson in the 4th capture group even though it is not surrounded by quotes. this could cause an issue if someone searched name:mark something-thats-not-a-name

Comment: @Wazimshizm So it should always be surrounded by quotes?

Comment: @Wazimshizm Or like this `\w+:(")?((\w+)(?:\h+(\w+))?)(?(1)")(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/dsZmJq/1

Comment: Or using a branch reset group `\w+:(?|(\w+)(?:\h+(\w+))?|"(\w+)(?:\h+(\w+))?")(?!\S)`  https://regex101.com/r/5XkDuu/1

Comment: no it doesn't always have to be surrounded in quotes, but if there's no quotes, only the first name will be captured. an example of a real search might be
`24 Main St, Seattle name:Doug date:06152020`
I'm just trying to extract the name part right now though. If someone wants to specify a last name, it has to be wrapped in quotes otherwise other parts of the search might be inadvertently picked up.

Comment: @Wazimshizm So like this `\w+:(?|"(\w+)(?:\h+(\w+))?"|(\w+))` https://regex101.com/r/sOZ4Bo/1

Answer (score 1):

The main point is that you cannot do that for arbitrary amount of groups, you must specify them all in the pattern at design time.

You may use a pattern like this with a [**branch reset group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html):

```
\w+:(?|(\w+)|"(\w+)(?:\h+(\w+))?(?:\h+(\w+))?")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qm59Ae/2). Add more `(?:\h+(\w+))?` patterns at the end to support up to N amount of optional words.

**Details**

- `\w+:` - 1+ word chars and then a `:`
- `(?|(\w+)|"(\w+)(?:\h+(\w+))?(?:\h+(\w+))?")`  - a branch reset group where groups share the same IDs:

  - `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
  - `|` - or
  - `"(\w+)(?:\h+(\w+))?(?:\h+(\w+))?"` -

    - `"` - a `"` char
    - `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
    - `(?:\h+(\w+))?` - an optional occurrence of a sequences:
    - `\h+` - 1 or more horizontal whitespaces
    - `(\w+)` - Group 2: one or more word chars
    - `(?:\h+(\w+))?"` - ibid, but with Group 3, etc.